# Can't open remote ssh directory after update

Tags: linux, windows, visual-studio-code, ssh

I have been using VSCode on a Windows laptop for an ssh remote directory on a Linux machine.  Things were working fine until an update of VSCode 1.68.0 and now I can't open the remote directory.

On Windows, the output says:

```
[12:55:24.183] Log Level: 2
[12:55:24.185] remote-ssh@0.82.1
[12:55:24.185] win32 x64
[12:55:24.226] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+ubuntu", attempt 1
[12:55:24.227] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[12:55:24.227] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[12:55:24.227] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {"runon":"linux","pfuntner-kube":"linux","everyday":"linux","kube":"linux","ubuntu":"linux"}
[12:55:24.227] "remote.SSH.path": C:\cygwin64\bin\ssh.exe
[12:55:24.228] "remote.SSH.configFile": c:\users\jpfuntne\.ssh\config
[12:55:24.228] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[12:55:24.228] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[12:55:24.228] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[12:55:24.229] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[12:55:24.229] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[12:55:24.229] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[12:55:24.229] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[12:55:24.229] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[12:55:24.230] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[12:55:24.230] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[12:55:24.230] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[12:55:24.239] SSH Resolver called for host: ubuntu
[12:55:24.239] Setting up SSH remote "ubuntu"
[12:55:24.247] Using commit id "4af164ea3a06f701fe3e89a2bcbb421d2026b68f" and quality "stable" for server
[12:55:24.254] Install and start server if needed
[12:55:24.257] Checking ssh with "C:\cygwin64\bin\ssh.exe -V"
[12:55:24.568] > OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021

[12:55:24.574] Using SSH config file "c:\users\jpfuntne\.ssh\config"
[12:55:24.575] Running script with connection command: "C:\cygwin64\bin\ssh.exe" -T -D 65341 -F "c:\users\jpfuntne\.ssh\config" ubuntu bash
[12:55:24.591] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[12:55:25.421] >                                  WARNING!!!
>                     READ THIS BEFORE ATTEMPTING TO LOGON
> 
>       This System is for the use of authorized users only.  Individuals
>       using this computer without authority, or in excess of their
>       authority, are subject to having all of their activities on this
>       system monitored and recorded by system personnel.  In the course
>       of monitoring individuals improperly using this system, or in the
>       course of system maintenance, the activities of authorized users
>       may also be monitored.  Anyone using this system expressly
>       consents to such monitoring and is advised that if such
>       monitoring reveals possible criminal activity, system personnel
>       may provide the evidence of such monitoring to law enforcement
>       officials.
> 
>       Cisco Acceptable Use Policy:
>       http://wwwin.cisco.com/c/cec/organizations/security-trust/infosec/policies
> .html]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[12:55:25.421] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[12:55:26.367] > 28e76cc256c4: running
[12:55:26.405] > Acquiring lock on /home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/4af164ea3a06f701fe3e89a2bcbb42
> 1d2026b68f/vscode-remote-lock.ubuntu.4af164ea3a06f701fe3e89a2bcbb421d2026b68f   
[12:55:26.430] > Installing to /home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/4af164ea3a06f701fe3e89a2bcbb421d20
> 26b68f...
> 28e76cc256c4%%1%%
> Downloading with wget
[12:55:33.759] > wget download failed
> failed: Connection timed out.
> printenv:
>     SHELL=/bin/bash
>     PWD=/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/4af164ea3a06f701fe3e89a2bcbb421d2026b68f
>     LOGNAME=ubuntu
>     XDG_SESSION_TYPE=tty
>     MOTD_SHOWN=pam
>     HOME=/home/ubuntu
>     LANG=C.UTF-8
>     VSCODE_AGENT_FOLDER=/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server
>     SSH_CONNECTION=10.82.235.230 65347 64.102.189.72 22
>     XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
>     USER=ubuntu
>     SHLVL=0
>     XDG_SESSION_ID=5
>     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
>     SSH_CLIENT=10.82.235.230 65347 22
>     PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
> :/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
>     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
>     OLDPWD=/home/ubuntu
>     _=/usr/bin/printenv
[12:55:33.764] > 
> Trigger local server download
> 28e76cc256c4:trigger_server_download
> platform==linux==
> vscodeArch==x64==
> destFolder==/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/==
> destFolder2==4af164ea3a06f701fe3e89a2bcbb421d2026b68f==
> 28e76cc256c4:trigger_server_download_end
> Waiting for client to transfer server archive...
> Waiting for /home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/4af164ea3a06f701fe3e89a2bcbb421d2026
> b68f/vscode-scp-done.flag and vscode-server.tar.gz to exist
[12:55:33.765] Got request to download on client for {"platform":"linux","arch":"x64","destFolder":"/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/4af164ea3a06f701fe3e89a2bcbb421d2026b68f"}
[12:55:33.765] Downloading VS Code server locally...
[12:55:33.770] > 
> 
[12:55:34.131] Resolver error: Error: Server returned 404
    at v (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/jpfuntne/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:622:38476)
    at k.download (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/jpfuntne/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:623:1592)
[12:55:34.136] ------
```

On Linux, all I have is:

```
$ find .vscode-server -type f | xargs -r ls -ld
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Jun 15 12:55 .vscode-server/bin/4af164ea3a06f701fe3e89a2bcbb421d2026b68f/vscode-remote-lock.ubuntu.4af164ea3a06f701fe3e89a2bcbb421d2026b68f
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Jun 15 12:55 .vscode-server/bin/4af164ea3a06f701fe3e89a2bcbb421d2026b68f/vscode-server.tar.gz
$
```

When I was first having trouble, I did `rm -rf .vscode` to fix things but it didn't help.

Can anyone help?

Comment: So the release notes don't make mention of any changes to the SSH client built-in to VS Code. It also looks like the connection process is attempting to connect correctly. What I noticed as being indicative of a problem, is this file 
vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/jpfuntne/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:622:38476)

Comment: That is where the error occurred in the connection process. I am not familiar connecting over SSH from windows to Linux, as I just always use Linux. If I were on windows I would just use WSL2 but thats a different story. The point is... The filepath shows it being opened as URI which is the contemporary standard, and to be expected, and it is using the VS Code resource identifier `vscode-file://` which means it is trying to open a file in VS code. A 404 Error was recieved, so that means it wasn't able to locate that file.

Comment: I actually suggest asking this on Super User, people who know more about SSH clients, and IT/Networking stuff in general frequent Super User far more than Stack Overflow. FYI: [Super User](https://superuser.com/) is Stack Overflow's Sister Site, so it looks & feels the exact same.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to start VSCode again today.  At first I thought it had the same problem but it looks like things are working ok now and I got in!

```
[07:14:44.009] Log Level: 2
[07:14:44.010] remote-ssh@0.82.1
[07:14:44.010] win32 x64
[07:14:44.048] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+ubuntu", attempt 1
[07:14:44.048] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[07:14:44.049] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[07:14:44.049] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {"runon":"linux","pfuntner-kube":"linux","everyday":"linux","kube":"linux","ubuntu":"linux"}
[07:14:44.049] "remote.SSH.path": C:\cygwin64\bin\ssh.exe
[07:14:44.049] "remote.SSH.configFile": c:\users\jpfuntne\.ssh\config
[07:14:44.049] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[07:14:44.049] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[07:14:44.049] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[07:14:44.050] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[07:14:44.050] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[07:14:44.050] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[07:14:44.050] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[07:14:44.050] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[07:14:44.050] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[07:14:44.050] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[07:14:44.050] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[07:14:44.056] SSH Resolver called for host: ubuntu
[07:14:44.056] Setting up SSH remote "ubuntu"
[07:14:44.062] Using commit id "4af164ea3a06f701fe3e89a2bcbb421d2026b68f" and quality "stable" for server
[07:14:44.068] Install and start server if needed
[07:14:44.071] Checking ssh with "C:\cygwin64\bin\ssh.exe -V"
[07:14:44.354] > OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021

[07:14:44.386] Using SSH config file "c:\users\jpfuntne\.ssh\config"
[07:14:44.387] Running script with connection command: "C:\cygwin64\bin\ssh.exe" -T -D 63895 -F "c:\users\jpfuntne\.ssh\config" ubuntu bash
[07:14:44.400] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[07:14:46.375] >                                  WARNING!!!
>                     READ THIS BEFORE ATTEMPTING TO LOGON
> 
>       This System is for the use of authorized users only.  Individuals
>       using this computer without authority, or in excess of their
>       authority, are subject to having all of their activities on this
>       system monitored and recorded by system personnel.  In the course
>       of monitoring individuals improperly using this system, or in the
>       course of system maintenance, the activities of authorized users
>       may also be monitored.  Anyone using this system expressly
>       consents to such monitoring and is advised that if such
>       monitoring reveals possible criminal activity, system personnel
>       may provide the evidence of such monitoring to law enforcement
>       officials.
> 
>       Cisco Acceptable Use Policy:
>       http://wwwin.cisco.com/c/cec/organizations/security-trust/infosec/policies
> .html]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[07:14:46.375] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[07:14:47.361] > cb747be286c8: running
> Acquiring lock on /home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/4af164ea3a06f701fe3e89a2bcbb42
> 1d2026b68f/vscode-remote-lock.ubuntu.4af164ea3a06f701fe3e89a2bcbb421d2026b68f   
> Installing to /home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/4af164ea3a06f701fe3e89a2bcbb421d20
> 26b68f...
> cb747be286c8%%1%%
> Downloading with wget
[07:14:54.685] > wget download failed
> failed: Connection timed out.
> printenv:
>     SHELL=/bin/bash
[07:14:54.692] > 
>     PWD=/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/4af164ea3a06f701fe3e89a2bcbb421d2026b68f
>     LOGNAME=ubuntu
>     XDG_SESSION_TYPE=tty
>     MOTD_SHOWN=pam
>     HOME=/home/ubuntu
>     LANG=C.UTF-8
>     VSCODE_AGENT_FOLDER=/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server
>     SSH_CONNECTION=10.82.240.153 63898 64.102.189.72 22
>     XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
>     USER=ubuntu
>     SHLVL=0
>     XDG_SESSION_ID=63
>     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
>     SSH_CLIENT=10.82.240.153 63898 22
>     PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
> :/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
>     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
>     OLDPWD=/home/ubuntu
>     _=/usr/bin/printenv
[07:14:54.695] > 
> Trigger local server download
> cb747be286c8:trigger_server_download
> platform==linux==
> vscodeArch==x64==
> destFolder==/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/==
> destFolder2==4af164ea3a06f701fe3e89a2bcbb421d2026b68f==
> cb747be286c8:trigger_server_download_end
> Waiting for client to transfer server archive...
> Waiting for /home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/4af164ea3a06f701fe3e89a2bcbb421d2026
> b68f/vscode-scp-done.flag and vscode-server.tar.gz to exist
> 
[07:14:54.697] Got request to download on client for {"platform":"linux","arch":"x64","destFolder":"/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/4af164ea3a06f701fe3e89a2bcbb421d2026b68f"}
[07:14:54.698] Downloading VS Code server locally...
[07:14:58.248] Downloaded VS Code server to c:\Users\jpfuntne\AppData\Local\Temp\03ba8324-01be-4f4c-bd89-538da94836ae
[07:14:58.253] Renamed VS Code server to c:\Users\jpfuntne\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode_server_1655378098249\vscode-server.tar.gz
[07:14:58.257] Checking ssh with "C:\cygwin64\bin\ssh.exe -V"
[07:14:58.555] > OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021

[07:14:58.581] Expecting scp to be next to ssh at C:\cygwin64\bin\scp.exe
[07:14:58.582] Testing scp with "C:\cygwin64\bin\scp.exe"
[07:14:59.442] scp exited with code: 1
[07:14:59.442] Got stderr from scp: usage: scp [-346ABCOpqRrsTv] [-c cipher] [-D sftp_server_path] [-F ssh_config]
           [-i identity_file] [-J destination] [-l limit]
           [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program] source ... target
[07:14:59.443] Using SSH config file "c:\users\jpfuntne\.ssh\config"
[07:14:59.445] Copying file to remote with "C:\cygwin64\bin\scp.exe" -F "c:\users\jpfuntne\.ssh\config" "vscode-server.tar.gz" "vscode-scp-done.flag" ubuntu:"/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/4af164ea3a06f701fe3e89a2bcbb421d2026b68f"
[07:14:59.447] Using cwd: file:///c%3A/Users/jpfuntne/AppData/Local/Temp/vscode_server_1655378098249
[07:14:59.447] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[07:15:00.744] >                                  WARNING!!!
>                     READ THIS BEFORE ATTEMPTING TO LOGON
> 
>       This System is for the use of authorized users only.  Individuals
>       using this computer without authority, or in excess of their
>       authority, are subject to having all of their activities on this
>       system monitored and recorded by system personnel.  In the course
>       of monitoring individuals improperly using this system, or in the
>       course of system maintenance, the activities of authorized users
>       may also be monitored.  Anyone using this system expressly
>       consents to such monitoring and is advised that if such
>       monitoring reveals possible criminal activity, system personnel
>       may provide the evidence of such monitoring to law enforcement
>       officials.
> 
>       Cisco Acceptable Use Policy:
>       http://wwwin.cisco.com/c/cec/organizations/security-trust/infosec/policies
> .html]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[07:15:01.620] > vscode-server.tar.gz                            0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA
[07:15:02.630] > vscode-server.tar.gz                           32%   17MB  17.0MB/s   00:02 ETA
[07:15:03.645] > vscode-server.tar.gz                           66%   36MB  17.1MB/s   00:01 ETA
[07:15:04.691] > vscode-server.tar.gz                          100%   54MB  17.4MB/s   00:03    
[07:15:04.705] > 
[07:15:04.722] > vscode-scp-done.flag                            0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA
[07:15:04.736] > vscode-scp-done.flag                          100%    9     0.7KB/s   00:00    
[07:15:06.150] "Copy server to host" terminal command done
[07:15:06.702] > Found flag and server on host
> cb747be286c8%%2%%
> tar --version:
[07:15:06.717] > 
> tar (GNU tar) 1.30
> Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>. 
> This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
> There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
> 
> Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
[07:15:08.979] > Checking /home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/.4af164ea3a06f701fe3e89a2bcbb421d2026b68f.l
> og and /home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/.4af164ea3a06f701fe3e89a2bcbb421d2026b68f.pid
>  for a running server
[07:15:09.019] > Starting server with command... /home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/4af164ea3a06f701
> fe3e89a2bcbb421d2026b68f/bin/code-server --start-server --host=127.0.0.1 --accep
> t-server-license-terms --enable-remote-auto-shutdown --port=0 --telemetry-level 
> all   &> "/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/.4af164ea3a06f701fe3e89a2bcbb421d2026b68f.
> log" < /dev/null
> printenv:
>     SHELL=/bin/bash
>     PWD=/home/ubuntu
>     LOGNAME=ubuntu
>     XDG_SESSION_TYPE=tty
>     MOTD_SHOWN=pam
>     HOME=/home/ubuntu
>     LANG=C.UTF-8
>     VSCODE_AGENT_FOLDER=/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server
>     SSH_CONNECTION=10.82.240.153 63898 64.102.189.72 22
>     XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
>     USER=ubuntu
>     SHLVL=0
>     XDG_SESSION_ID=63
>     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
>     SSH_CLIENT=10.82.240.153 63898 22
>     PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
> :/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
>     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
>     OLDPWD=/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/4af164ea3a06f701fe3e89a2bcbb421d2026b
> 68f
>     _=/usr/bin/printenv
> rm: cannot remove '/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/.4af164ea3a06f701fe3e89a2bcbb421d
> 2026b68f.token': No such file or directory
[07:15:09.029] > 
> Spawned remote server: 60287
[07:15:09.036] > 
> Waiting for server log...
[07:15:09.052] > 
[07:15:09.080] > Waiting for server log...
[07:15:09.146] >  
> *
> * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products,  
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057) 
> *
> 
[07:15:09.171] > cb747be286c8: start
> SSH_AUTH_SOCK====
> DISPLAY====
> webUiAccessToken====
> listeningOn==35689==
> osReleaseId==ubuntu==
> arch==x86_64==
> tmpDir==/run/user/1000==
> platform==linux==
> unpackResult==success==
> didLocalDownload==1==
> downloadTime====
> installTime==2258==
> extInstallTime====
> serverStartTime==122==
> connectionToken==1a1a1a1a-1a1a-11a1-aa1a-1111a1111a1a==
[07:15:09.184] > cb747be286c8: end
[07:15:09.184] Received install output: 
SSH_AUTH_SOCK====
DISPLAY====
webUiAccessToken====
listeningOn==35689==
osReleaseId==ubuntu==
arch==x86_64==
tmpDir==/run/user/1000==
platform==linux==
unpackResult==success==
didLocalDownload==1==
downloadTime====
installTime==2258==
extInstallTime====
serverStartTime==122==
connectionToken==1a1a1a1a-1a1a-11a1-aa1a-1111a1111a1a==

[07:15:09.185] Remote server is listening on 35689
[07:15:09.185] Parsed server configuration: {"serverConfiguration":{"remoteListeningOn":{"port":35689},"osReleaseId":"ubuntu","arch":"x86_64","webUiAccessToken":"","sshAuthSock":"","display":"","tmpDir":"/run/user/1000","platform":"linux","connectionToken":"1a1a1a1a-1a1a-11a1-aa1a-1111a1111a1a"},"installTime":2258,"serverStartTime":122,"didLocalDownload":true,"installUnpackCode":"success"}
[07:15:09.193] Starting forwarding server. localPort 63909 -> socksPort 63895 -> remotePort 35689
[07:15:09.195] Forwarding server listening on 63909
[07:15:09.195] Waiting for ssh tunnel to be ready
[07:15:09.257] [Forwarding server 63909] Got connection 0
[07:15:09.260] Tunneled 35689 to local port 63909
[07:15:09.260] Resolved "ssh-remote+ubuntu" to "127.0.0.1:63909"
[07:15:09.272] ------




[07:15:09.300] [Forwarding server 63909] Got connection 1
[07:15:09.650] [Forwarding server 63909] Got connection 2
```

On Linux:

```
$ find .vscode-server -type f | wc
   1798    1798  196423
$
```